# How to find element by xPath in Ghost Inspector

Tags: automation, ghost-inspector

Hi have to click an element using its xPath in Ghost Inspector but its not working for me, the syntax I tried were:

1. `"xpath=".XPATH`
2. `"xpath="XPATH`
3. `xpath=.XPATH`
4. `xpath=XPATH`

all the above thing that I tried didn't worked and Ghost Inspector was saying:

> "ELEMENT NOT FOUND"

can any one please help me finding element using its xPath in Ghost Inspector

Answer (score 3):

you should use **xpath=//**

For example: **xpath=//*[@id="main-container"]/div[1]/my-header/div**

Documentation: https://ghostinspector.com/docs/test-editor/#targets

Comment: This is now automatically generated on paste.

Answer (score 2):

I am using developer tools in Chrome and there I can choose (by mouse right click) what value I want to copy. Try to copy xPath, it should work, I use them a lot.

Comment: Ghost inspector as of today will format the xpath for you correctly. Copy the xpath from your console (or construct it by hand like it's 1999) and paste it in to the selector section, it will prepend it with `xpath=//` for you